Using openssl with FIPS mode on my own image
I have a custom image that is based on Red Hat.
OpenSSL 1.1.1 is installed, but it is not FIPS compliant, and upgrading to openssl 3+ is not possible.
For a specific app, I need FIPS compliant version of openssl 1.1.1.
I took the following version from Red Hat and successfully ran on my machine:
OpenSSL 1.1.1k  FIPS 25 Mar 2021

It is currently not running in FIPS mode, in Red Hat you need to execute the fips-mode-setup script that will transition the OS to FIPS mode, my OS is a bit different and I can't ran it.
Is there an option I can manually force openssl to use it's FIPS mode ?
I'm expecting openssl to fail calculate md5 after FIPS mode is enabled
EDIT:
Tried:
OPENSSL_FIPS=1 ./openssl md5 /dev/null

and received:
FIPS mode not supported.

EDIT 2:
I managed to run the fips-mode-setup script and now:
FIPS mode is enabled.

But can't run openssl
crypto/fips/fips.c:154: OpenSSL internal error: FATAL FIPS SELFTEST FAILURE
Aborted (core dumped)


There are definitely some libraries that get mismatched. What's your OS? How did you install the custom version? What's (where's) the default one? Check [SO]: How to compile python3 on RHEL with SSL? SSL cannot be imported (@CristiFati's answer) or [SO]: How to enable FIPS mode for libcrypto and libssl packaged with Python? (@CristiFati's answer).
